# ASP tags inside HTML Comment

Tags: html, asp.net

Recently I was looking through an ASP.Net Website. And I saw in one of the Master Page file a ContentPlaceHolder inside an HTML comment, like this:

```
<!-- <asp:contentPlaceHolder runat="server" id="titleBar"/> -->
```

When I run the website in IIS Server, the website runs fine. But in Visual Studio, the second master page that inherits the first master page (the one with the above line) has a Content tag that refers to the 'titleBar' placeholder. It is shown as a warning and the design view cannot parse the code, says 'Could not find titleBar in the current master page or pages'. But IIS runs it. Is the above line valid, or is there a setting in Visual Studio to parse the above line?

If you want to see the actual code, it is in "C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\ASP.NETWebAdminFiles". It is the old Web Administration Tool.

Comment: That looks like a mistake. Have you tried uncommenting it?

Comment: `is there a setting in Visual Studio to parse the above line?` - I don't think so.

Comment: @Tim That's not a mistake. I just looked at the generated source, it actually creates HTML comment dynamically when changing pages. So that means it is valid. But visual studio doesn't agree.

Comment: "it actually creates HTML comment dynamically when changing pages" - what do you mean by this?

Comment: That line is actually inside a master page. So every HTML content in that master page is included in every page that inherits that master page. Not just the HTML content, but I'm new to ASP.NET. So the comment is also included in every page. But, inside the comment is an asp tag with runat="server". So the server actually parses the asp and generate the result, which is placed inside an HTML comment. Sou when we view the source of each page through the browser, there will be different comments based on which page the browser is accessing. A dynamically generated comment.

Answer (score 0):

The asp tags placed inside HTML comment tags is parsed by the server. But Visual Studio will not parse it. It shows up as an error. But IIS can, and we can see the result when we use View Source from browser. But I still cannot see whether this is a valid use of asp tags or not. We know that asp tags are parsed from anywhere within the aspx file as long as it is not inside a Server Side Comment (<%-- --%>). I was only confused because the IDE will not parse it. I cannot use design of the page. But when run from the server, the page loads up correctly and the said comment portion has text which the asp tag generates.